# problem with urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code used to print out a web page.  It now prints a single space, even though that page clearly has content when viewed in a browser

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
f = urlopen('http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-tips.html?mod=topnav_2_3000')
page = f.read()
f.close()
print('*', page.decode(), '*')
```

This started when I upgraded from 3.2 to 3.2.1, but that could just be a coincidence

What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: works in 2.6. doesnt work in 3.2.1. no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Python 3.1 and Python 3.2, but not Python 3.2.1 (it returns an empty string).

EDIT: I've reported it in the Python-Dev list.

Comment: It's a known bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue12576.  A fix will be in  Python 3.2.2.

Comment: The fix is already in the 3.2 maintenance branch if you want to pull the latest source (http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#getting-the-source-code).

Comment: You *could* try to download the file from the repository.  This is a link to the current (at this moment) top of the 3.2 maintenance branch and it appears the fix was isolated to that one file.  But there may be earlier dependencies.  And you may need to tweak line endings depending how you download:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/14b25e4a5591/Lib/urllib/request.py

Comment: That appears to work, based on limited testing. More changes than just from the link I posted above your comment.  Thanks